# Can somebody point me to print the text in table row/column using protractor

Tags: javascript, html, protractor

Here's how my html page looks like:

```
<table class="service ng-scope">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
    24 HOUR TREND
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to print the text '24 HOUR TREND' in my test using protractor.

Here's my test code:

```
describe("print text", function () {

    var ptor;

    beforeEach(function() {
        // get protractor instance
        ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    });

    it("print text", function() {
        var modal;
        // load the url
        ptor.get("/");
        var elements = ptor.findElements(protractor.By.className('service ng-scope'));

        < -- Problem here --- what to do --- >

        // disable jQuery animation effects
        ptor.driver.executeScript("$.fx.off = true;");
});
```

Comment: This is a fairly active community, that answers questions quite fast :)

I posted this question while ago and nobody replied yet. Not sure if my question is too d** or nobody knows the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
ptor.get("/");
var serviceTable = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.className('service ng-scope'));
serviceTable.getText().then(function(text) {
  console.log(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this worked. However I got:

Message:
     InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names are not supported. Consider searching for one class name and filtering the results or use CSS selectors.
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:14:00'

So ended up just using:

protractor.By.className('ng-scope')